# Process a file by dragging it on windows shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I am developing an windows application, which will be installed on users computer. And user should be able to drag a file onto the shortcut of the installed application & the application should process the file. Is there any event I can listen to which will allow me to process dropped file?

Comment: im pretty confident that isn't possible. but you could add a `reg-edit` value to show a `windows context menu` script for a certain file type. It could use the file path as an argument and calls your application with said argument.

Comment: @thanatorr yes I was also thinking of the same option of having a context menu. I have worked more on web platform & I could not find anything related to my requirement on SO myself, so asked question.

Comment: good luck finding it, ill follow in interest of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `Program.Main` to accept command line arguments

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(args != null)
        {
            //handle args here...
        }
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: if I create a installer package & dropped a file on its shortcut will that accept a file?

Comment: I tried creating a shortcut of the executable and dragged a file on the shortcut and still got the filepath.